# Pass a variable to read_csv as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

To be more user friendly, I have created a prompt for the user to input a file path.

```
print('Please enter file path surrounded by quotes.')
path = 'r' + input()
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False))
```

When input is

```
"C:\path\somefile.csv"
```

Output returns

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'r"C:\path\somefile.csv"' does not exist: b'r"C:\path\somefile.csv"'
```

If I remove the variable input and drop the file directly into the read_csv argument, it works just fine. Can someone educate me?

Comment: Don't add "r" to the beginning of the input string. Also, if you're using Python 2.x, use `raw_input` instead of  `input` so you don't have to type the quotes.

Comment: also you are missing one closing parentheses ") " on line `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False)` or simply do `df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False)`

Comment: Why are you inputting with quotes: `"C:\path\somefile.csv"`? Just remove the quotes, and don't add the `r`. That doesn't make it a raw string, that just *adds and r*

Comment: I suggest you learn about the difference between the "repr" of a string the value of a string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would you mind explaining to me why you must use r in front of the quoted file path when you enter it as a direct argument rather than passing it through a variable?

Comment: Because that is a *raw string literal*. That is *source code*. There is a difference between source code and your data. `input` takes user input from the standard input stream and returns it as string object. String *literals in source code* are surrounded by quotes, but no quotes exist in the data itself.

Comment: Thank you that makes things much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were over-engineering your code. It's as simple as this:

```
print('Please enter file path without quotes.')
path = input()
df =pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False)
```

You don't need the quotes, as they will be added automatically

Comment: I don't even think `replace(r'\\','/')` is necessary

Comment: works, thank you! I've had issues inputting file paths before where r"some path" has always fixed the issue, so I've always used it without issue. This is the first I've had where it has actually caused a problem. Guess I need to research it's use more.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing raw string literals with a string value. When we write something like

```
csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:\path\somefile.csv')
```

the `r'C:\path\somefile.csv'` is a string literal. This is how we represent the string **in python code**. The user should never be aware of the `r''` notation, including both the letter `r` and the quotes. Instead, they should just type the path as they see it in other programs. This means that you can just do

```
path = input()
```

Also the user shouldn't be required to type any quotes.